# my imageView not refreshing and giving java null pointer Exception

Tags: android

my ImageView is always trying to re-use the same bitmap whereas whenever i tap (onTap ()) it 's supposed to go look for the right image not using the same. How can I prevent it to so??
besides, whenever i recycle it, my activity crshes when i tap again...

Please help!

my logcat gives me:

```
03-14 14:40:15.519 D/setting image>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>(29389): grrrrr java.lang.NullPointerException
```

here is my snippet :

```
 protected boolean onTap(int i) {
               /*   Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                  locations.get(i).getSnippet() + " " + locations.get(i).getTitle(),
                                  Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();*/
                 //   mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapView);
                  OverlayItem item=getItem(i);
                  GeoPoint geo=item.getPoint();
                  Bitmap bitmap = null;

              Point pro=    mapView.getProjection().toPixels(geo, null);
                  if (pro!=null)
                  {   View view=panel.getView();



                 /* }
                  catch (Exception e){Log.d("merde>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>", "grrrrr " +e);}*/
              String capteur=   getType (locations.get(i).getSnippet()); 
                  ((TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.poptext))
                    .setText(String.valueOf("image captured by : " + capteur + "\n" + "Latitude = " + locations.get(i).getPoint().getLatitudeE6() +" " + "Longitude = "+ locations.get(i).getPoint().getLongitudeE6() +" " + 
                             "\n" + "Image can be found at the following directory :" + locations.get(i).getTitle()

                            ));

                  if (locations.get(i).getTitle()!=null){
                try {

                       bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(locations.get(i).getTitle());} catch (Exception e){Log.d("getting Title>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>", "grrrrr " +e.getMessage());}
                      if (bitmap!=null){
                          try{
                              mContext=getApplicationContext ();
                             ((ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ImageV)).setImageBitmap(bitmap);



                      } catch (Exception e){Log.d("setting image>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>", "grrrrr " +e);}}

                      else {}

                  }else {}
                  panel.show(true

                          );}

                  return(true);
                }
    my popup panel

class PopupPanel {
    Context mContext= getApplicationContext();
        View popup;
        boolean isVisible=false;

        PopupPanel(int layout) {
          ViewGroup parent=(ViewGroup)mapView.getParent();

          popup=getLayoutInflater().inflate(layout, parent, false);

          popup.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
              hide();
            }
          });
        }

        View getView() {
          return(popup);
        }

        void show(boolean alignTop) {
          RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp=new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
          );

          if (alignTop) {
            lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP);
            lp.setMargins(20, 20, 20, 20);
          }
          else {
            lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM);
            lp.setMargins(20, 20, 20, 60);
          }

          hide();

          ((ViewGroup)mapView.getParent()).addView(popup, lp);
          isVisible=true;
        }

        void hide() {
          if (isVisible) {
            isVisible=false;
            ((ViewGroup)popup.getParent()).removeView(popup);
          }
        }
```

Comment: if you got exception always put logcat then someone else know whats prblm

Comment: my logcat gives me only null pointer Exception

Answer (score 0, accepted):

one thing I can tell you right away is that e.getMessage() doesn't really works. It'll return null and you'll get null pointer exception.

**update**

well, i can tell you that too,

```
((ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ImageV)).setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

when you call that and say

```
findViewById(R.id.ImageV)
```

The view R.id.ImageV is inflated someplace else and what you are getting here is just an raw ref. to that view. You need to have referece to the actual view which originally inflated that view and then through that view you can call

```
myOldView.findViewById(R.id.ImageV)
```

that'll definately solve your problem.

Comment: it's working here giving me "null" as string..
Anyway my problem lies where i setBitmapImage

Comment: I'm realy interested in what you are saying and i think it is the right direction.. can you be more explicit??
my english is not that strong

Comment: ok, the findViewById(R.id.ImageV) will return null as it is equals to this.findViewById(R.id.ImageV), because that view is not inflated by your activity. The view is inflated by some other view. So somewhere in your app you have someViewName.findViewById(R.id.ImageV), that someViewName need to call the R.id.ImageV again.

Comment: all you are saying is correct, actually i'm using a popup panel class.. let me add that tell me where i should put someViewName.findViewById(R.id.ImageV)

Comment: if i understood your code right you should be able to call popup.findViewById(R.id.ImageV), and that should work

Comment: onTap(int i) function is not part of PopupPanel class?

Comment: no no it is not, the ontap is part of itemizedoverlay and it calls the popupanel class

Comment: so you have to pass your view object to popuppanel class so you can use it in popuppanel

Comment: i think i'm lost there, everything i tape is put in red :(
I'll try to read more, may be i'll figure it out

Comment: you were right, i just had to put view.find.findViewById(R.id.ImageV).. not that i've doubted you before ;)

Answer (score 0):

There is only two thing can be null

- `ImageView` ->if that is the case make sure you are using layout in which IamgeV is defined

*. `Bitmap`, but it is not the case because you have already verified that things in if condition

so make sure you are using correct layout file or you are passing the correct ImageView Id

Comment: i've checked they are both corect... Proof is that, at first time the image is hsown but when i click again, it gives me the old image and null pointer exception

Comment: In the catch part write e.printstaktrace() and than put the log cat hear so community can have more idea